# Proof of the formula for the probability of throwing heads after n throws?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a known formula for the probability of throwing a heads after consecutively throwing heads. It goes like this:

$$P(n) = (1-p)^{n-1}p,$$

where $n$ indicates the nth throw and $p$ indicates the probability of throwing a heads.

So for example, if we have thrown 3 heads, then the probability of throwing a heads on the 4th throw is $$P(4)=(1-p)^{4-1}p=(1-p)^3p=\frac{1}{16},$$ and subsequently the probability of throwing a tails is $15/16$.

I've tried to think about this to prove the formula but I'm very unsure. Of course, if the probability of throwing a heads is $p$, then $P(1)=p.$ This fits the formula. The next logical step that would allow one to pretty much derive the formula would be to say that the probability of throwing a heads on the second throw is $P(2)=p(p-1)$ because the probability of throwing a tails is $p-1$. And then $P(3)=p(p-1)(p-1)$ and so on.

However, I don't really understand this logic. Could someone explain?

Comment: This just reflects the fact that each toss is independent.  The probability of any given string of tosses is just the product of the probabilities of each specified toss.

Comment: That formula gives the probability that the *first* head appears on the $n$th throw (so, it's the probability that the first $n-1$ throws are tails and the $n$th is a head).

Comment: @DavidMitra I thought that, but while writing the question I noticed that as $n$ increases, $P(n)$ becomes smaller. Surely as a string of tails gets longer the probability of throwing a heads becomes higher...?

Comment: You're committing the gambler's fallacy there.

Comment: @Randall Yes but what David is saying is that the longer the string of tails, the higher the likelihood of throwing another tail. (Since the equation indicates that the probability of throwing a head decreases as n increases.) How does that make sense?

Comment: That's not quite what it says.  It says the probability of running a long string of tails and then getting a head goes down as the length of the string gets longer, which is true.  It doesn't mean the chance of hitting that last head is anything other than 50/50 by itself.

Comment: @Randall Ah I see. That makes much more sense, thank you. So basically this formula is not saying "Given n-1 failures, what is the probability of success?"; it is saying "What is the probability of a success on the nth attempt following n-1 failures?". However, of course each throw has an 50% probability of being heads or tails independent of all other throws.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is not well formulated. The probability of a head **after** you have seen $n-1$ heads is still $p$, if you assume independence. On the other hand, the probability of getting $n$ heads when throwing the coin $n$ times is $p^n$ (before the experiment is performed).

The formula you presented is one used in the context of a Bernoulli random variable $X$, which assumes value $X=1$ (often called success) with probability $p$, and $X=0$ (often called a failure) with probability $(1-p)$.

The formula gives us the probability of getting a success after $n-1$ failures, for a size $n$ random sample of $X$. Yes, in the coin toss example you can assume that "heads" is a success and "tails" a failure, but in this case $p=(1-p)$, and the result is just $p^n$. It will be different if for your coin the probability of heads $\not =0.5$.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the case you mention in your second paragraph, and I was using heads-tails as an example with P(H) not equal to P(T).

Would you mind editing your answer to explain the logic involved in coming up with the formula in the context of a coin toss with unequal probabilities of each outcome?

Comment: @ODP: the probability of a H (head) after 4 T (tails), in a experiment consisting in throwing a coin 5 times, is, before the experiment is performed: $P(T\cap T\cap T\cap T\cap H)=P(T)P(T)P(T)P(T)P(H)=(1-p)^ {4} p$, as the events are assumed as independent, and $P(H)=p$.

Comment: Should that not be $P(T\cap T\cap T\cap T\cap H\cap ) = (1-p)^4p$ with $P(H)=p$

Comment: Sure, I've just fixed that in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

@bluemaster 's answer is correct. I think your question needs further comment.

The essence of your problem is the sentence that begins

> So for example, if we have thrown 3 heads, then the probability of
>   throwing a heads on the 4th throw is

It should end

> just $p$, because what has happened in the past has no influence on
>   what will happen next.

Your mistake is in thinking that since "in the long run" the probability of heads is $p$ on the average somehow the coin needs to "catch up" after a run of some tails. That is the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy), and has cost naive gamblers lots of money over the years.